# Selinux what's the right context for module like imagemagick /usr/bin/convert

Tags: linux, centos, selinux

I have an application I need to call from php,  but selinux is preventing execmem for the application. I want to set the right context rather than allow bin_t or httpd_user_script_t execmem access.  I don't have imageimagick installed on the server unfortunately, I wanted to copy the same context.  can anyone check this or let me know what's the best way to solve this without opening a security hole on the server.

Answer (score 1):

From `httpd_selinux(8)` manpage, I think one of this contexts can suffice, depending on your config:

`httpd_exec_t
       - Set files with the httpd_exec_t type, if you want to transition an executable to the httpd_t domain.`

httpd_suexec_exec_t
       - Set files with the httpd_suexec_exec_t type, if you want to transition an executable to the httpd_suexec_t domain.

Comment: Thanks, that helped with setting it as httpd_t.  but I wanted avoid giving httpd_t execmem access. but I guess I have no choice for now.  I still would love to know what is the context used for /usr/bin/convert (imagemagick) as usually this works fine. maybe there is another context.

Comment: Chech the manpage I have referenced, all the possible contexts are explained there. Also check `matchpathcon(8)` and `semanage(8)`